# log4net with SQLite: InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory' to type 'System.Data.IDbConnection'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sqlite, log4net

Using log4net, When i try to open a SQLite database under App_Data folder in my Asp.net application am getting this following error in trace file.

> log4net:ERROR [AdoNetAppender] ErrorCode: GenericFailure. Could not
>   open database connection [Data
>   Source=|DataDirectory|\databasefile1.db;Synchronous=Off]. Connection
>   string context [ConnectionString]. System.InvalidCastException: Unable
>   to cast object of type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory' to type
>   'System.Data.IDbConnection'. at
>   log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.CreateConnection(Type connectionType,
>   String connectionString) at
>   log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.InitializeDatabaseConnection()

Version Details:

- .NET Framework 4.5.1
- SQLite 1.0.93.0
- log4net 1.2.11.0

I tried changing my sqlite database location but same error occur.

in Global.asax.cs,

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", Server.MapPath("~/"));
        XmlConfigurator.Configure(); 
    }
```

in AssemblyInfo.cs,

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile="Web.config", Watch= true)]
```

In Web.config

```
<log4net debug="true"><appender name="sqlite" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender"><bufferSize value="1"/><connectionType value="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.93.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139"/><connectionString value="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\databasefile1.db;Synchronous=Off"/><commandText value="INSERT INTO LogTable(message) VALUES (@message)"/><parameter><parameterName value="@message"/><dbType value="String"/><layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout"><conversionPattern value="%message"/></layout></parameter></appender><root><level value="ALL"/><appender-ref ref="sqlite"/></root></log4net>
```

Comment: Please show your log4net config, I guess the problem is in there (log4net section in web.config).

Comment: Hi Peer, updated the question with log4net config

Comment: Hi there was an error in connectiontype section on log4net tag in web.config, need to change that value System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory to System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection, that has solved the InvalidCastException error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem is in you connectionType configuration (System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory):

```
 <connectionType value="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection, System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.93.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139"/>
```

This is copied from the [config samples](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html), you have to adjust the type and version setting to your sqllite version.

Comment: I fear that am not into that Finisar version of SQLite and am using System.Data.SQLite version, Thanks for your efforts peer, I made a mistake in connectiontype, pls look into my latest comment if you missed.

Comment: Then you need to find the equivalent of the SQLiteConnection, which is not the SQLiteFactory. Just googled it for you, see updated answer.